# I rescued this white leaf nerve, fittonia, exotic angel plant for $1

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

[image]

I want to know how to bring it back. Will the tin lantern in the picture work as a terrarium or make a mess?

I thought I could make it an outside hanging plant as the counter space in my bathrooms are full of succulents and lucky bamboo.

Comment: The gardener put it in direct sun and flooded with water. I want sure what it was, no tag. The man at gardening center said I could bring back the leaves not dead yet . It's been less than 24 hours so far.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the edit!